# how to change default form template in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, user-interface

i want to specially designed form for my vb.net application.
i am designed one form. it is border less form.
now i want use it use as form template instead default windows form.

can it use as user control.
sorry my poor English

Comment: You could use inheritance. There’s also ways to make new templates

Comment: If you want to save a Form or Control as Template, open up the `Project->Export Template` wizard, choose `Item Template`, next select the item (a Form class here) to export, skip the `Select Item References` if not strictly required, so you can use the Template in .Net Framework or .Net  Projects (unless of course you're using assemblies that target a specific .Net version), add an Icon and a preview image (if available, it's not required but this gives the Template it's own *visual identity*); keep the default output location.

Comment: You should find the new Template in the usual `Add...-> Form (Windows Form)` interface. In older versions of Visual Studio there might be a couple of steps more, but the core procedure doesn't change.